# What does it mean that $f$ achieves its minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f:C\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such that
$$f(x_0) =\inf_{x\in C} f(x).$$

Does it mean that $f$  achieves its minimum?

It is not clear for me, I hope someone could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "$f$ achieves its minimum on $C$" means "there exists a point $x_0\in C$ such that for every $x\in C$, one has $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$." Now, based on the definition of infimum, can you verify whether this is true/false?

Comment: @peek-a-boo what you wrote means, in particular, that $f(x_0)$ is a minorant for $f$. Since the minimum is the bigger of minorants, thus it should be true, isn't it?

Comment: The statement is true, but I'm not sure what you mean by "since the minimum is the bigger of minorants..."

Comment: I would say the infimum, not the minimum, I am sorry. And thank you for your comment.

Comment: Here is something you should be able to figure out directly from definitions. If $A\subseteq \mathbb {R} $ is non-empty such that $\inf A$ exists and $\inf A\in A$ then $\inf A$ is also the minimum element of $A$. Now let $A=\{f(x) \mid x\in C\} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what "achieves its minimum" means. To put it another way, a function $f$ achieves its minimum on a set $X$ if there is an $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

There is an important theorem relating to this: if $f$ is continuous on a nonempty *closed interval*, then it achieves its minimum and maximum values on that interval.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that $f$ achieves its infimum and maximum because by definition a function always achieves its minimum and maximum when such exist.

Comment: In that case, it would be _even  more_ correct to say that $f$ achieves its infimum and supremum :-)

Comment: @md2perpe: That is true, but the terminology I'm using can be found in analysis textbooks. In Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, he writes on page 123 that "Theorem 3 is often paraphrased by saying that a continuous function on a closed interval 'takes on its maximum value'". I'm not defending the logical precision of such a statement, and I agree that your statement makes more sense.